# Merged Google Fusion Tables - Select Query with WHERE clause on Merge Key Error

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I have merged two Fusion Tables together on the key "PID". Now I would like to do a SELECT query WHERE PID = "value'. The error comes back that no column with the name PID exists in the  table. A query for another column gives this result:

```
"kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "\ufeffPID",
  "Address",
  "City",
  "Zoning"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "001-374-079",
   "# LOT 15 MYSTERY BEACH RD",
   "No_City_Value",
   "R-1"
  ],
```

It appears that the column name has been changed from "PID" to "\ufeffPID", which no matter how many attempts to get the syntax to read a GET Url, I keep getting an error.

Is there any limitation with querying on the key of a merged table?  Since I cannot seem to get the name correct for the column a work around would be to use the Column ID but that does not seem to be an option either.  Here is the URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT '﻿PID','Address','City','Zoning' FROM 1JanYNl3T45kFFxqAmGS0BRgkopj4AS207qnLVQI WHERE '\ufeffPID' = 001-493-078&key=myKey

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have no explanation for \ufeff in there; that's the Unicode character  'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE', so it's conceivable that it's actually there in the column name because it would be invisible in the UI. So, first off I would recommend changing the name in the base tables and see if that works.

Column IDs for merge tables have a different form than for base tables. An easy way to get them is to add the filters of interest to one of your tabs (any type will do) and then do Tools > Publish. The top text ("Send a link in email or IM") has a query URL that has what you need. Run it through a URL decoder such as http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and you'll see the column ID for PID is  col0>>0.

Rod